# VBA or excel formula for data aggregation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel which has a list of companies and various people who are working on the companies each company may have 5-7 people associated with a company.
the table is structured as company name, person1, person 2... in cells

I need an approach in VBA or excel formula wherein based of this table, I wish to have the names of companies associated with each person
for eg. person1 - list of all companies he is working on in cells below his name.

I have basic knowledge of VBA, any approach or solution is highly appreciated.

I am not allowed to embed images yet. so the link
source table:   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9sj3.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMyy8.png

[image]

Desired output:  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9sj3.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8QxU.png

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure in your case but have you considered using Pivot tables?

Comment: Yes, I did but pivotables don't seem to provide the needed output. Like I have about 12 persons assigned to around 40-50 companies (multiple persons assigned to single company and the person has multiple companies in his coverage, basically any 4-6 people can be assigned to a company). What I need is if I have a name of person in a cell, all the companies he is working on to be displayed below his name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could change your data like in the picture with two columns, you could still use a pivot table to get a list of companies per person. For instance by filtering like in the picture (sorry for the Dutch layout).

[image]

Otherwise, if you at least know all the names of the people, I would suggest the following sort of loop in VBA

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim wst as worksheet
Dim i,j,k as long
Set ws = Thisworkbook.sheets("SheetNameData")
Set wst = Thisworkbook.sheets("SheetNameLists")
For i = 2 to ws.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'Assuming you have headers, start at row 2
   For j = 2 to ws.cells(i,columns.count).end(xltoLeft).column 'Loop through all names in a companyrow
     k = application.worksheetfunction.match(ws.cells(i,j).value,wst.range("1:1"),0) 'find the right column in the output worksheet
     wst.cells(rows.count,k).end(xlup).Offset(1,0).value = ws.cells(i,1).value 'Place the companyname in the column of the right person
   Next j
Next i
```

For this script, you need to already have a second sheet where the first row consists of the people's names

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have provided the link for images of what I am trying to accomplish. Since, I have multiple columns pivotable unfornutaely does not serve the purpose. I will give you code a try.

Comment: Code worked like a charm, although in my case I have two sets of tables,one beside the other with a column gap between them, will try to tweak the code and accomplish the output. Thanks so much

Comment: @Alex FYO, this code will `Dim` `i` and `j` as `Variant`, not `Long`